# How to remove object from array in Mongoose using updateMany?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get an object removed from an array in MongoDB using Mongoose/Node and so far I have been unable to get it removed. I have read docs and SO posts to no luck. I'm hoping someone could give me specific advice on a solution not just a link to another post which is vaguely related

Mongo document example

```
{
  managers: [{
      userID: value,
      // other fields and values
    },
  // Another object for another manager
  ]
}
```

Code I am trying to use

```
await Model.updateMany(
  {'managers.userID': userID}, // This should be the query part
  {$pullAll: {'managers': {'userID': userID}}} // This should be the update part
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) you have to match the whole object.

Apart from the syntax is not correct in your query, check how in [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8J9J4lLlMqg) the `id` 1 is not removed but it is the `id` 2. That's because `$pullAll` expects to match the whole object. And [this other example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q2ZD0o73tWa) works removing both `ids`.

Then, to do your query you can use `$pull` and `$in` like this:

```
await Model.updateMany({
  "managers.userID": userID
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "managers": {
      "userID": {
        "$in": userIDs
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaguG6JsMMA)

Note how `$in` expects an array. If you only want to remove based on one value you can avoid `$in`:

```
await Model.updateMany({
  "managers.userID": userID
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "managers": {
      "userID": userID
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/11pNPAEY97S)

Comment: Thanks, so when I try this it does nothing. It seems to be running on 0 documents. However if I copy a document from the DB manually and inset that into the playground and then modify the userID in the second section to match the value I console.log() in my code then it works as expected. Maybe this is caused by the update vs updateMany having a different way of doing things?

Comment: Is `userID` an `ObjectId`? Maybe you are trying to compare string with `ObjectId`. As fas as I know UpdateMany is the same as mongo Update with `multi:true`.

Comment: Figured it out, nothing wrong with your answer. It was an issue of axios not sending the value for the DB connection to my backend properly.